# systemd LogsDirectory with DynamicUser=yes that is readable by regular users

Tags: linux, service, systemd

From what I understand, when using `LogsDirectory=foo` with `DynamicUser=yes` in systemd service, the directory is created as a symlink to a private directory, that is readable only by root.

My service's logs do not contain any private information and I'd like regular users to be able to read them. Is there a way to allow that, like with `systemd-journal` group for journal access?